# How do I login with Facebook credentials on my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4

I have a web application that authenticates users against Facebook.  Once my site redirects them to login with Facebook, FB redirects them back to my site with a valid session cookie.  This is a PHPCOOKIE I guess.

I would like to accomplish the same thing from my iPhone application.  I have looked at the Facebook iPhone SDK, but that simply lets the iPhone application directly call the graph API.

What I actually want to do is have my backend server call the graph API like it does with the browser.

How do I get the iPhone SDK to pass the session cookie to all requests to my server, the same way the browser does?

Answer (score 0):

This does actually occur- but you're on the iPhone, and the iPhone caches the "cookie" with auth info. It's in NSDefaults. It's also called single-sign-on or SSO. It detects Facebook login and authentication on the native app on the same device, and sets a local (iPhone app default) access token for further graph requests.

Comment: But I do not see the cookie passed onto my website when I make subsequent requests.

Comment: So you want to send the app-user's authentication token (access token) to your PHP web site? Why? Does the user use something done on that site? Is there some kind of call, etc.?

Comment: My website in turn uses the Facebook php ask to access Facebook.  I want my iPhone app to behave like the web browser does with respect to how it interacts with my php site

Comment: So.. my point is that you don't *need* to log into the php site, you can do it all from the phone.

Comment: Anna., I'm not that dumb... There are things my php site does on behalf of the user that I don't want to duplicate all the code into my iPhone app.  I simply want the php site to not know the diff between a phone and a browser

Comment: Sorry did not mean to offend- I have several apps that use a server for various heavy lifting, if you send the access_token, your php/server code can use that on behalf of the user. It depends on how you build your server apps, to discern iphone vs. web user.